# Does a contributed desktop app build on Node.js require the user Node.js environment installed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

As the title already says:

If I contribute my Node.js desktop app which has been build with electron, does the users which install my program need the Node.js environment have installed on their computers?

So like the same with Java to run a Java app?

Comment: It depends how you build/ship the application... Are you shipping a plain JS file? or is it built on electron or something?

Comment: I agree with @Salketer, this is too vague right now to get an accurate answer. Which frameworks do you use for instance? What is your app doing? Is it supposed to be run in a webbrowser?

Comment: sorry I mean if it is build with electron